# Can WSUS server be used to deliver updates to PCs outside an organization?

Tags: networking, windows-10, windows-update, wsus

We would like to deliver Windows 10 updates to PCs that we ship with our our software. These PCs can be deployed in other organizations or in standalone environments at various sites without being connected to a domain controller.

Is it possible to use WSUS to deliver updates to such remote systems outside of our organization?

I am asking because my initial understanding is that WSUS only manages updates for network computers within a single organization or intranet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot.

First off, it is against the EULA as you can't make updates available to anyone outside your organization.  Organization meaning company, business, etc.  Obviously, remote employees on company computers are in your organization.

Secondly, how would these remote computers connect to your WSUS server?  Remote employees VPN in, which allows updates to be applied.  You definitely wouldnt want to have WSUS server open over the internet and have all the ports open on both ends to connect them.

Comment: Making a non-Domain computer use a WSUS server is fairly easy (just insert the registry keys the domain group-policy normally would set manually in the computers registry), but you don't want to play Microsoft to the rest of the world. It won't be long before you are dealing with Microsofts legal department. And Microsoft can afford the best lawyers money can buy. That won't end well...

Comment: @Tonny That is true, you dont need *Active Directory* for WSUS.  I dont know if those changes would work over the Internet though.  Even if it did, it just a bad idea.  The OP is better off looking at other software designed to deliver updates over the Internet.

Comment: They do work over the internet, just like the normal WindowsUpdate. The mechanism is identical. But exposing your Wsus server to the net... It can be done but it takes a lot if work to secure it. And there is redundancy, scalability and maintenance to consider as well.

Comment: I don't know too much about WSUS yet but was exploring it to deliver updates to customer's PCs that we ship. Given that's not legally possible with WSUS, what are the other options? Our scenario is that we approve Windows updates first before customers can install them and we want to automate this.

Comment: @Zar About the only thing I can come up with is the open source tool WsusOffline, which can be modified to exclude/include specific Windows updates and also allows for other stuff to be integrated (e.g. driver and/or non-Microsoft software updates). And which will handily generate an installation DVD and/or a folder with files for USB or zip-file deployment. Using it to bundle WindowsUpdates into a deployable set won't get you in any legal issues. It is what I use to keep computers updated that, for various reasons, are not connected to the internet or our internal LAN.